# how can I show an alert after a dynamic div is created without reload the page and js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can I show an alert after a dynamic div is created?  Something like this

```
   jQuery("#id").load(function($) {
      alert("hello");
    }); 


 function methodName(channel){
       $.ajax({
       type: "get",
       dataType: 'html',
       data: { param1: param1 , param2: $('#abc').find(":selected").val()},
       url: "/xxx/"+ $('.xyz').attr("attr1") +"/yyy",
       success: function(data, status){ 
         var obj = JSON.parse(data),
         tmplHTML_measures,
         data_graph;
         var template_data = { 
           measures_list:   
             obj.measures         
         };
          $(function() { 
               tmplHTML_measures = '{{#measures_list}} <div class="col-lg-11  col-lg-offset-1"><p class="indicator-title gray-bottom-border">{{name}}</br></p><div><p><span class="font30px">{{total}} </span> Total {{name}}<br><span class="green-text">{{percentage}}%</span> from last <span class="metric_time"></span></p></div><div class="graph-header"><h3>{{this_interval}} </h3><p>New {{name}}</p><p class="percentage-graph green-text">{{increase}}%<p></div><div id={{graph_id}} class="graph"></div> </div>{{/measures_list}}';
               Handlebars.render = function(tmpl, data){data = data || {};return Handlebars.compile(tmpl)(data);};
               $("#template").empty().append(Handlebars.render(tmplHTML_measures,template_data));         
               var data_graph;
              for ( var measures_cont = 0; measures_cont < obj.measures.length; measures_cont++ ) {
                    data_graph = obj.measures[measures_cont];
                    populateGraph(data_graph.this_interval_detail,data_graph.last_interval_detail,data_graph.graph_id,time_text,obj.bottom_graph_text,parseInt(time.attr('interval')) );           
      }      
    })        
  },
  error: function(error) {

}
 });

 return this;
};
```

This is my code, I remove some code, but here is the main code, in tmplHTML_measures I create the div, exactly in  id={{graph_id}} and I populate the chart in populateChart function. The main page has many pictures so when the user click on a picture I draw  chart, so I draw a the chart many times

Comment: Create dynamic div how? `.html()` `.append()` ...?

Comment: I use handlebar for that, with .append(), but I cant reload all .js because highcharts.js give me the error #16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check out the docs for .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#id").load("url", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "success") {
    alert("hello!");
  }
});
```

Comment: this always reload the page? the problem with that is what reload all .js and this give me an error with highcharts.js, the error #16,so I can t reload the page

Comment: This shouldn't reload the page, What's the error you're getting with Highcharts?

Comment: Highcharts Error #16 Highcharts already defined in the page. A little more details in http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16. Thanks

Comment: That seems like a conflict with your Highcharts js calls, What'ts the URL you're trying to load with .load()?

Comment: I am very new with that, so I tried with an empty string, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes that's wrong, what's creating your dynamic div? Can you post that code?

Comment: I update my original code, sometimes work perfectly but sometimes give me the error #13 http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13 Rendering div not found

Comment: Why not just put in an alert() after your Handlebars call in the ajax success function?

Comment: What I need is time untill handlebar complete to render the div, sometimes handlebar complete before populateChart starts to work and sometimes not, by the way thanks you so much for all answers

Comment: Run a function after the handlebars method that checks to see if the div has a class of rendered or something, and if it does, do the alert!